# Removing string from each element in an unordered list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Happy People</li>
   <li>Sad People</li>
   <li>Angry People</li>
</ul>
```

And I'm wanting to remove "People" including the space before the word. How would I go about doing that in jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(' People', '') );
});​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/WgQUq/)

---

Also, for more complex use-cases:

If there's markup inside the list items, use `.html()` instead of `.text()`: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/WgQUq/5/))

```
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace(' People', '') );
```

If you want to warrant that " People" will only be matched at the end of the string: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/WgQUq/3/))

```
$(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ People$/, '') );
```

And if you want case-insensitive match, add the `i` flag to the regex: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/WgQUq/4/))

```
$(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ People$/i, '') );
```

All of the above have the same output for your minimalist example.

Comment: That worked! Actually, I had put in the text version first and my layout went crazy, but then I tried the .html one and that worked wonderfully. Thank you for that!